# How does Django handles Custom Validation?

Tags: django-models, django-forms

For example I have a particular method inside my modelform class. Does Django internally invoke all methods in that class even without me explicitly invoking that method?

Does the is_valid() method internally invoke all methods in my modelform class?Coz I want to create a custom validation method in my form. does django internally call that method?

Answer (score 0):

For form custom validation try using [`clean()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/validation/) - it will automatically get called with the standard validation.